# Не могу сгенирировать hash key для фейсбука

Tags: android

Раблтаю с фейсбук апи. такая проблема. я генерирую hash key приложения

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "C:\Users\zen_75\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl"
sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
Enter keystore password:
```

далее ввожу пароль(какой пароль я незнаю поэтому придумываю любой либо пустой пароль, поразному пробовал).

генериться ключь. вставляю в фейсбук. Но он все равно ругается типо hash key не правильный. и показывает вообще другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> далее ввожу пароль(какой пароль я незнаю поэтому придумываю любой либо
>   пустой пароль, поразному пробовал).

Пароль для `androiddebugkey` - `android`

Попробуй по частям, возможно на одном из этапов оно падает:

сначала keytool, посмотри какой у него вывод, потом keytool+openssl sha1, и потом все 3

Comment: я ввел пароль  android  и все заработало!!!!!!!!!!!!!! я потратил несколько дней! огромное спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!